# From indicator random variable into probability using fundamental bridge?

Tags: probability, random-variables, expectation

I'm a newbie studying probability. Let I be an indicator random variable. A and B be an event. Then:

$$I_{A \cup B} = I_A + I_B - I_A I_B$$

I want to go from this equation into this equation:

$$P(A \cup B) = P(A) + P(B) - P(A \cap B)$$

From the fundamental bridge which says $P(A) = E(I_A)$ we can use Expectation and Linearlity property to derive the second equation from the first equation. Then:

$$I_{A \cup B} = I_A + I_B - I_A I_B$$
Becomes:
$$E(I_{A \cup B}) = E(I_A + I_B - I_A I_B) $$
$$P(A \cup B) = E(I_A + I_B - I_A I_B)$$
how can I solve the right hand side??? Now my question is you can see on the right hand side there is a problem. From the Linearity of Expectation, I can break $E(A+B)$ into $E(A) + E(B)$ and I can also break E(cA) into cE(A) where c is a constant but can I also break $E(I_{A1} + I_{A2} - I_{A1} I_{A2})$ into $E(I_{A1}) + E(I_{A2}) - E( I_{A1}) E (I_{A2})$ ? is this valid? breaking $E(I_{A1} I_{A2})$ into $E(I_{A1}) E( I_{A2})$ is ok? is $I_{A1}$ and $I_{A2}$ considered as a constant??? if it is, why? can someone please explain to me in very detail?

if it is valid then we will get:
$$P(A \cup B) = E(I_A) + E(I_B) - E(I_A) E (I_B)$$
Then:
$$P(A \cup B) = P(A) + P(B) - P(A)P(B)$$

My second question is, since $P(A)$ is independent from $P (B)$ (because indicator random variable is distributed as Bernoulli distribution), so the above equation can be thought of as:

$$P(A \cup B) = P(A) + P(B) - P(A \cap B)$$

which coherence with the union of event theory.

Am I understand correctly? or I have make some mistake here? Something I miss understand? please give me step by step consistent and precise explanation.

Comment: $E(I_A I_B)=E(I_A) E(I_B)$ does not hold in general; it is true only when events $A$ and $B$ are independent.

Comment: then there will be a contradiction because $P(A \cup B) = P(A) + P(B) - P(A \cap B)$ holds for event A and B no matter they independence or dependence. if the fundamental bridge theory is correct there must be some ways to prove from the first equation into the second equation using fundamental bridge? can someone show it?

Comment: Expectation $E(I_A I_B)=P(A \cap B)$ but, in general, this is not equal to $E(I_A) E(I_B)=P(A) P(B)$.

Comment: Alright I see, so in detail we can write $E(I_A I_B)= E(I_{A \cap B}) =P(A \cap B)$ Am I understand correctly?

Comment: Note that $I_{A}I_{B} = I_{A\cap B}$.

Comment: @user3270418 Yes, that is correct.